# Multivariate analysis in split-plot designs

Tags: r, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, split-plot, crossed-random-effects

I am struggling to find the appropriate analysis with a microbial dataset.
Here is the experimental design I have to work with:
[image]
Basically I have plants from a first generation that grows in different treatments.
These plants produced seeds that were sowed in either their mother's treatment or "transplanted".
The second generation was then sampled for diverse measurements as well as microbiota assessment.

I want to investigate the effects of past and current treatments and, if possible account for the mother identity on measurements of the second generation. My design is both nested and crossed corresponding I believe to a form of split-plot design and I have multiple questions.

If I were to investigate single variable response I should use linear mixed models (am I right?) but can't find the appropriate model structure in R syntax.

And, much more tricky, is there a method that you know of allowing to test the effects of past and current treatments on the second generation microbial communities? Could I check the relative contribution of these two sets of treatments to the observed microbiota? And if so, what would be the tools in R as I don't think that vegan (dbrda like analysis) support this kind of designs.

I am not sure that what I look for exists and I am thus open to suggestions about how you would do to account for this kind of designs? Would a combination of sequential and marginal test of past and current treatment in a dbrda be acceptable?

I acknowledge that its a quite open post and that my question is not very clear but I can't find a better place where to discuss this.
Thank you for your answers and time.
Cheers